# Dump php system command output to a file

Tags: php, system, command, background-process

In the php system command we use the following

```
system("ffmpeg -i test.avi -ab 56 -ar 44100 -b 200 -r 15 -s 320x240 -f flv output_file.flv 2>&1 &").
```

Please explain the usage of the above mentioned system command. What does '2>&1 &' stand for ? I want to dump the process details to a file how do I do that ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

`2>&1` redirects [«`stderr`»](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) to [«`stdout`»](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29), `&` at the end makes the command run in [background](http://www.astro.ku.dk/comp-phys/tutorials/background.shtml).

To make it complete it should be

```
«command» 2>&1 > /tmp/somefile.log &
```

Without redirecting «`stdout`» to a file (or to [`/dev/null`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_sink)) running in background from `system()` doesn't make much sense, as your command would get killed as soon as PHP terminates (e.g. reaching time limit).

From [`system()`](http://www.php.net/system) manual:

> Note: If a program is started with
>   this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background,
>   the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output
>   stream. Failing to do so will cause
>   PHP to hang until the execution of the
>   program ends.

Answer (score 1):

2>&1 redirects the Standard Error (2) log to Standard Output (1).

Not sure what the extra & at the end does.

If you want to pipe stderr or stdout to a file, you can do that easily.

To pipe stderr to a file, change 2>&1 to 2>filepath

Where the filepath is preferrably an absolute filepath (ex: 2>/home/user/output.mpg)

Answer (score 1):

Every UNIX program has two output streams: stdout and stderr. For redirection purposes, the > symbol redirects stdout (file descriptor 1) to a file. The "2>" redirects stderr (file descriptor 2) to a file, represented in this case by "&1" which tells the shell to use file descriptor 1 (which is stdout). In a php context this means that both streams will be printed in your script output, which you now doubt have figured out.

The & at the end of the command tells the shell to run the job in the background. I don't know why you would want to do this in this environment.

Comment: Putting a & makes the command run without waiting for output. This could help in running concurrent PHP scripts. Imagine 100 cUrl calls sequentially, in comparison to running them in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to a file via PHP, you can also use `[exec()][1]` or `[passthru()][2]` which have options to return all of the content from a command. `system()` will only return the last line.